# Where did my image go? Background images with flexbox

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I have an image that's supposed to sit above the columns and below the navigation bar at 100 vh's of height. However, while the space where the image is supposed to be is there, the image itself seems to have disappeared. The URL does point to a site as well so it's not as if it's broken. I'm trying to figure out why my image isn't rendering and what I can do to help it render.
 What's a good way to do this using Flexbox? Is flexbox even the most efficient way?

This is my HTML:

```
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300i" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
 <nav>
   <li><a href = "#"> Home</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#"> Heading1</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#"> Heading2</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#"> Heading3</a></li>
 </nav>
    </header>

  <div class="hero">
  </div>


  <div class="container">
      <div class="side1">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="main-content">
      <h2>Main-content</h2>
        <p>
          "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="side2">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
          <p>
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS...

```
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  width:100%;
}

header {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px    rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 display: block;
  margin-top:-10px:
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: black;
  height: 30%;
  padding-right:0px;
}

.hero {
height: 100vh;
background: url(https://www.pexels.com/photo/coffee-writing-computer-blogging-34676/);
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

nav {
  display: block;
}

nav li {
  font-weight: 700;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;

  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

li {
  border-top: grey solid 1px;

}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height: 45px;
}

li:nth-child(1){
  border-top: none;
   padding-bottom:10px;
  margin:0px;
}

li:nth-child(2){
padding-top:10px;
margin:0px;

}

li:nth-child(3){
margin:0px;
padding-top:10px;

}

li:nth-child(4){
margin:0px;
padding-top:10px;

}


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.side1 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px    rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  width:100%;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-content {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px    rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

 width:100%;
 background: white;
 border-color: black;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.side2 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px    rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 width:100%;
 background: white;
 border-color: black;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width : 726px) {


@media screen and (min-width : 900px) {
  .header {
  display:flex;
    }

    header {
      -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
     box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px    rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      width: 100%;
      align-items: center;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: white;
      border-color: black;
      height: 30%;
      padding: 10px;
}


    nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

    li:nth-child(1){
      border-top: grey solid 1px;
       padding-top:10px;
      margin:0px;
    }

  .container  {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .main-content {
    border-left: lightgrey 1px solid;
    border-right: lightgrey 1px solid;
    width: 33.3%;
  }

  .side1 {

      width: 30%;
  }


  .side2 {

    width: 30%;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background url for class `.hero` is incorrect. Use this instead:

`background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/34676/pexels-photo.jpg);`

The url you're currently using links to a site that displays the image, not the image itself (which is what you want for your background).

Comment: thanks it works but how did you get to that picture of the image? I decided to go with another image but I need to be able to do what you did

Comment: inspecting the image with devtools will show you the image element and its "src" attribute, which is the url of the image itself. as an example, if you right-click that url and choose 'open in a new tab', you should see only the image in the new tab, and you can use the url in the location bar to link to the image from your page